# size of segment control segment

Tags: ios, objective-c

For the purpose of adding an image to a segment control, how can I  determine the dimensions of a control box in a segmented control? [image] For example, there are four boxes in the segmented control in the image above but they can be stretched if the segment control itself is stretched. How can I find out the size of any of the boxes so that I know how big to create an image I wish to set for the control?

Update - this code gives an `expected expression` error when I try to use `widthForSegmentAtIndex` below

```
- (IBAction)segmentChosen:(id)sender {
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl*) sender;
    switch ([segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex]) {
        case 0:
            CGFloat widthOfWantedSegment = [segmentedControl widthForSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: They are a big as you want them to be. You can use `setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:` to set their width.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, even if i set it up initially in storyboard? just create an outlet and set width on the outlet property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I find out the size of any of the boxes so that I know how big
>   to create an image I wish to set for the control?

By using the `UISegmentController` instance method `-widthForSegmentAtIndex:`

Ref: [UISegmentedControl Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html)

---

```
CGFloat f_widthOfWantedSegment = [segmentController widthForSegmentAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: Hi I updated the OP with my attempt to use the method but it gave me an error. Can you add a bit more to your answer based on my error. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Leahcim : this works in tandem with a fixed segment width. Basically, when you explicitly set a fixed size for a segment using `-setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:` instead of the default "auto" width. And as per your question... `expected expression` doesn't look like it's due to `-widthForSegmentAtIndex:`. _Anyways... i'll either delete/update this answer later_.

Comment: I was able to get `-setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:` to work, however, I wanted to find out the size of the segments created by the storyboard (i.e. before I set the width in code using above method) but couldn't get it to work (as you know), so please show me how when you have a minute using the code i put in the update. Thank you kindly if you can....